# AWS windows EC2 machine not accessible in browser and not able to ping

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using default VPC i edited the VPC's inbound and outbound rules of main NACL to ALLICMPv4 protocol allow 0.0.0.0/0

COnfigured the security group inbound and outbound with ALL Traffic and individually allowed HTTP and HTTPS and ALLICMPv4 allowed for 0.0.0.0/0

Created a new rule to allow Inbound and Outbound traffic for ICMP protocol in "windows defender firewall advanced security" in my machine to make sure the ICMP is not blocked.

My EC2 is having a public ip assigned to it. All the subnets associated with the VPC are public and have internet gateway attached to them.

Even after these steps my AWS ec2 windows machine is not able to reach in browser and not pinging. I not sure what is missing??

Please someone help me here!!

Comment: It would appear that you are wanting to connect to the Amazon EC2 instance via HTTP/S. Have you installed a web server on the instance? Are you able to login to the instance via RDP?

Answer (score 0):

Able to reach the AWS EC2 instance Public IP in browser. We need to create windows defender firewall rule for inbound by select the "PORT" option when you create a new rule. Follow the below video for the same.
https://youtu.be/DJOq2gXDdpc

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).